# Difference between Iterating over BTreeMap and &BTreeMap

Tags: rust, ownership

I am trying to understand the difference between

```
let rows = Vec::new();
for (k, v) in my_btree { // BTreeMap<i64, String>
    rows.push((&k, &v)) // k and v don't live long enough.
}
```

and:

```
let rows = Vec::new();
for (k, v) in &my_btree { // BTreeMap<i64, String>
    rows.push((k, v))
}
```

Can someone please explain the difference between iterating over `&my_btree` and iterating over `my_btree`?

Specifically I would like to understand how ownership changes and what memory is being referred to in both of those examples above

Here is a full example of what I am trying to do (target_function is a library I am working with that has a function signature like it has here, so that can't change):

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

struct SomeStruct {
    x: BTreeMap<i64, String>
}

fn target_function(rows: &[(&i64, &String)]) {
    for row in rows.iter() {
        println!("{:#?}", row);
    }    
}
fn test(ss: SomeStruct) {
    let mut rows = Vec::new();

    for (k, v) in &ss.x {
        rows.push((k, v));
    }
    target_function(&rows[..]);
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = BTreeMap::new();
    a.insert(1, "hello".to_string());
    a.insert(2, "goodbye".to_string());

    let mystruct = SomeStruct{x: a};
    test(mystruct);
}
```

Comment: The difference actually is in `(&k, &v)` and `(k, v)`. Both snippets work with `rows.push((k, v))` and neither work with `(&k, &v)`.

Comment: Short answer: When iterating over `&my_btree`, the values are borrowed, so you get references with a lifetime tied to the collection. But when iterating over `my_btree`, you get owned values. If you create references of them, they are only alive until `k` and `v` go out of scope.

Comment: @Zefick: thanks for your answer, but I am forced to have references in the end (see my code block at the bottom) which is why I have the (&k, &v) and it was mostly to demonstrate why those are different from each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subtlety with this is with the double implementation of `IntoIterator` for `BTreeMap` (and most collections, actually). You can see it in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#impl-IntoIterator), in order:

- `impl<K, V> IntoIterator for BTreeMap<K, V>`

This is your first case. What you are doing is moving the `BTreeMap` and consuming it to produce a `(K, V)` iterator. You can convince yourself of this with the following snippet:

```
let mut my_btree:BTreeMap<i64, String> = BTreeMap::new();
my_tree.insert(3, "this is a test".to_string());
let mut rows = Vec::new();
for (k, v) in my_btree { // BTreeMap<i64, String>
    rows.push((k, v))
}
```

This consumes `my_btree` and yields `(K, V)` pairs, one by one. Since these pairs are *owned*, you can safely push them into the `Vec` you provided. In your snippet, you had `&k` and `&v` - and these references would never work seeing as the items would be immediately dropped from scope.

- `impl<'a, K, V> IntoIterator for &'a BTreeMap<K, V>`

This is your second case. In this case, your iterator is now `(&'a K, &'a V)` and you can easily convince yourself of this by trying to move the `Vec` out of scope of the `BTreeMap`, like so:

```
fn does_not_work<'a>() -> Vec<(&'a i64, &'a String)> {
    let my_btree:BTreeMap<i64, String> = BTreeMap::new();
    let mut rows = Vec::new();
    for (k, v) in &my_btree { // BTreeMap<i64, String>
        rows.push((k, v))
    }
    rows
}
```

This will not compile because you inserted a bunch of references to elements in your `BTreeMap`, and you then drop it (due to it moving out of scope) - all those references would be invalid if the borrow checker didn't come to the rescue.

So, that is the difference - in one case, you are consuming the `BTreeMap` to operate on owned structs, in the other you are working on references.

Your example functions due to this - you are never actually dereferencing the map due to the `&ss.x` iterator, which never consumes the map.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! That really helps. I had missed the fact that there were two different `IntoIterator`'s

Comment: @Nick there are three, actually, but the third one is obvious (`&'a mut BTreeMap`), and was not immediately relevant for this question.